# mod_rewrite not working consistently

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I've got a rewriting scheme going on that was working fine. Basically, anything in the url is passed as a querystring to *index.php*, so */dave/bob* is rewritten to */index.php?page=dave/bob*. I deal with the parsing of this in *index.php*. Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The problem I'm having is that sometimes the url is displaying incorrectly in the address bar. See these two examples: [working](http://goldseal.skilldrick.co.uk/about) and [not working](http://goldseal.skilldrick.co.uk/contact). The same problem occurs with the services page. For those of you who'd rather not visit external links, *goldseal.skilldrick.co.uk/contact* is displaying as *goldseal.skilldrick.co.uk/contact/?page=contact* in the address bar.

As you'll see, I'm currently working in a subdomain, which is being redirected to a directory under */public_html*, using cpanel. Might this be the cause?

Comment: I added the "apache" tag to help you find people who can answer your question, please revert if that's not the correct tag for your question.

Comment: Is there any other rule that can get in conflict with this one?

Comment: Thanks Pascal. @Gumbo Maybe, but not under my control (I'm on a shared server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm an idiot, but I've worked it out!

The reason services and contact were both causing problems was because I already had dirs under public_html/goldseal called /services and /contact (from a previous incarnation of the site), so the rewrite rule was getting confused when I told it to go to /contact.

Thanks for all your help, and sorry for wasting your time :P

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a "/" in front of index.php.

Comment: Wow, no freaking idea - I just tested it in my sandbox and it worked fine.  Just for giggles, can you put "&foo=bar" after "page=$1" and let me know what happens w/the two URLs?

Comment: I've now got `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)?$ /index.php?page=$1&foo=bar [L]` but still doing the same thing :( I'm guessing there's some kind of conflicting rewrite going on with the subdomain that's causing trouble. Putting a trailing slash on the url works though!

Comment: That's weird, now it's putting in the foo=bar: `http://goldseal.skilldrick.co.uk/contact/?page=contact&foo=bar`

Comment: Wait, try this "RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&foo=bar [L]"

Comment: I've tried that - for some reason when I deleted the slash I forgot to delete the question mark. Still doing the same thing though.

Comment: Hmm, not sure.  Well anyway, did you change something b/c the link you have above that says "not working", is working for my just fine.